# create function that takes variable name and works with shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm able to create a function that takes a data frame and a variable name. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(100, 1, 1),
                 y=runif(100,0,10))

test <- function(data, variable){
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  x <- as.character(arguments$variable)
  t <- sum(data[,x])
  return(t)
}
# This works
test(df, x1)
```

But the same function does not work with shiny. For example:

````
---
title: "BUG"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

# SET UP

```{r}
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(100, 1, 1),
                 y=runif(100,0,10))

test <- function(data, variable){
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  x <- as.character(arguments$variable)
  t <- sum(data[,x])
  return(t)
}
```

# THIS DOES NOT WORK

```{r}

selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
            colnames(df))

test(df, input$variable)
```
````

What am I doing wrong?

---

This example shows how what I want is possible with `ggplot2`

````
---
title: "ggplot2 works"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

# This works

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

# This also works

```{r}
library(shiny)
inputPanel(
  selectInput("x", "x:", c("wt", "mpg")),

  selectInput("y", "y:", c("mpg", "wt"))
)
environment<-environment() 
myplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(get(input$x), get(input$y)), environment = environment) + geom_point()

renderPlot({
  myplot
})

```
````

Comment: I guess you are over-complicating things. Just define `test` as `test<-function(data, variable) sum(data[,variable])`. You want that `test(df, "x1")` works and not `test(df, x1)`. See the difference?

Comment: Your function is written using non-standard evaluation. You are expecting a symbol name and deparsing that to a character. When you run `test()` with `input$variable`, your `x` variable is literally `"input$variable"`. (Note this is not specific to Shiny in anyway.) Your `input$variable` value will already be a string. Don't bother with the `match.call` and `as.character` stuff in your function. Just pass a character value and you'll have no problems.

Comment: @nicola. I want my function to work when i run `test(df, x1`). I'm trying to avoid requiring the quotes

Comment: @MrFlick I'm not sure i'm following your solution. I think your solution would require me to do `test(df, "x1")` and `test(df, x1)` would not work

Comment: You can't build an expression that way in Shiny. And input will never return a symbol. You can cast it but that would be even uglier. Non-standard evaluation is better when running interactively. It is not good if you are trying to programmatically build expressions. Use the character method.

Comment: Why you want to avoid the quotes? If you want a function that calculates the sum of a column of a `data.frame`, just pass a variable that stores the *name* of the column. It's one of the most simple things you can do in R.

Comment: @nicola, i'm just using that function as an easy reproducible example. I want to avoid the quotes because I like how `dplyr`, `ggplot2`, etc do it.

Comment: "I want to avoid the quotes because I like how dplyr, ggplot2, etc do it" is not a reason. Those packages obey to a different logic, and let you also pass the name of a variable. You want to do something depending on an input which is a `character` vector (the value passed by `shiny`). Just write a function that *takes* a character vector. Simple as that.